# MySQL Varchar Type outputs starting/ending spaces

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okai, so my problem is that one of my URL's get unvalid because my SQL table outputs a space before and after the actuall URL string. 
I added some pictures and some code for guidance.

```
<a href="..">
    <img src="../
         <?php
             $fetchheader = $db->prepare("SELECT background FROM header ORDER BY id DESC");
             $fetchheader->execute();
             $headerall = $fetchheader->fetchAll();
             $fetchheader->execute();
             echo $headerall[0]['background'];
         ?>
     ">
</a>
```

Here are some pictures aswell to explain the problem:

Here you can see that the type is set to varchar:
[image: Here you can see that the type is set to varchar]

Here you can see that the output on the websites causes errors:
[image: Here you can see the output error on the website]
[image: Error]

Comment: Just a side note: try to get all vars done before theming output. You can write more compact and easier to read code, e.g. `print '<img src="../' . $path . '">'`

Comment: +1 ^^^ Definitely agree with Paul's comment ^^^. You're going to have a LOT of code for any additional images/`href`'s, should that be the case later on.

Comment: Sidenote: A suggestive approach would be to use a `WHERE` clause and fetch from DB first, assign a variable to it. That way, you could easily change your background in that one line. By creating a new table with a column and multiple rows. I.e.: `"SELECT background FROM img_backgrounds WHERE background = 'bg_1'"` then you can just change the `bg_1` to `bg_2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have left empty spaces between HTML and `<?php`/`?>`, what is reason you got  in your image path, so you should remove these spaces:

```
<img src="../<?php
         $fetchheader = $db->prepare("SELECT background FROM header ORDER BY id DESC");
         $fetchheader->execute();
         $headerall = $fetchheader->fetchAll();
         $fetchheader->execute(); // <-- probably this is not necessary :)
         echo $headerall[0]['background'];
     ?>">
```

Comment: It would probably be better to echo out the entire image element. then the code can be refactored however you like.

Comment: I agree with you. But the question is why he has spaces in his image path, so be it :).

Comment: you definitely fixed the problem - was just a side note really.. and Paul gave very similar comment

Answer (score 0):

can you try it?

use trim() to remove unwanted spaces in php

```
$background=trim($headerall[0]['background']);
```

or

```
$background=$headerall[0]['background']; preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $background);
```

If you want to replace the blank space in MYSQL

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE( `col_name` , ' ' , '' )
```

Comment: It will not fix the problem. Problem is in HTML not PHP.